# Library import error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library

i need to import tow external library to my project;

1-android-support-version 7(that added correctly)

2-a list-view animation library.

that my project not add last library(list-view animation).

at first adding , this worked right , but after deleted and added again this not work.

i try several time to adding library from several location,then restart the eclipse but this have problem yet and can't find library :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the drive,where your workspace is located.Delete your list view animation library from workspace **in your hard disk**(i.e. manually from the drive) and try again.That should work.If not,then create a new workspace and import again.

Comment: i delete from workspace too; but not work - this may that .metadata folder have problem!!?

Comment: no - i delete on disk - now , can find library but root folder of project iv eclipse have Exclamation point!!!

Answer (score 0):

OK

finally i find problem.
i copy all library in my project Drive(hardware location) and add Libraries again.
clean project and rebuild it.
it work!